# Is it possible to shift a string character by two unit only by swapping?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, swap

Is it possible to shift a string character by two unit only by swapping. I know we can easily do it by second array . What about only swapping  . Is there is a way to proof solution exist or not?

Comment: for example hacker will result in erhack

Comment: Any permutation can be composed from swaps. A recursive solution is: swap the first element into place, and then swap the rest of the elements into place.

Comment: Shift it by one, but do it twice.

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, don't ask yes/no questions and don't add important info as comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `<algorithm>` library you could simply use `std::rotate`:

```cpp
std::string s = "hacker";
std::rotate(s.begin(), s.begin()+(s.size()-2), s.end());
std::cout << s;
```

or, you could use `std::reverse`:

```cpp
std::string s = "hacker";
std::reverse(s.begin(), s.begin()+(s.size()-2)); 
std::reverse(s.begin()+(s.size()-2), s.end()); 
std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end()); 
std::cout << s;
```

Output: `erhack`

Comment: If you're going to use the standard library you might as well use [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

Comment: @Blastfurnace Yes, your right! That would be more relevant as well, as `std::rotate` is for solely such purposes. Thanks for commenting that, it didn't clicked in my mind, and I ended up going the long way - edited :)

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
void stringShift(std::string& string, std::size_t count) {
    count %= string.size();
    for (long long i = string.size() - count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        std::swap(string[i], string[i + count]);
    }
}
```

Possible to add a check that `count != 0`, for efficiency reasons.